# Is there a way an object only partly visible when it is partly through a border

Tags: unity-game-engine

The title is a little confusing I know but I have a box that objects need to descend into (see image) is there anyway to make it so that the arrow isn't visible when outside the box but becomes visible when it enters the box.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q0yw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this, would be to use a [sprite mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html).
Put the sprite mask object on your box, then change `Mask Interaction` to `Visible Inside Mask` on your arrow.

Here's some screenshots of what I did for reference:

Box:

[image: box inspector]

Arrow:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.